# How to correctly use MDQuerySetSortComparatorBlock in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, spotlight

My code:

```
//search all of applications
let queryString = "kMDItemContentTypeTree=com.apple.application"

// sort by last metadata change
let sorting = [kMDItemAttributeChangeDate] as CFArray

// create query and assign sorting param
let query = MDQueryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, queryString as CFString, nil, sorting)
        
// ISSUE HERE
// Set comparation block that called for sorting
MDQuerySetSortComparatorBlock(query, {
            if let date1 = $0 as? Date,
               let date2 = $1 as? Date {
                  return date1 < date2 ? .compareLessThan : .compareGreaterThan
              }
            
            return CFComparisonResult.compareEqualTo
        })


MDQuerySetDispatchQueue(query, DispatchQueue(label: "background", qos: .background) )
MDQueryExecute(query, CFOptionFlags())
```

issue is in correct way to write MDQuerySetSortComparatorBlock - I'm do not understand how is it must be written

I see warnings:

> Cast from 'UnsafePointer<Unmanaged?>?' (aka
> 'Optional<UnsafePointer<Optional<Unmanaged>>>') to
> unrelated type 'Date' always fails

Comment: `Unmanaged` is always such fun.  I think you have to call either `.takeRetainedValue()` or `.takeUnretainedValue()`. I'm guessing the former.  So I think it would be `if let date1 = $0?.pointee?.takeRetainedValue() as? Date`

Comment: @ChipJarred thanks, it works! post it as an answer)

Comment: I'll do that.  I'm glad my guess, albeit a hazily informed one, was right (or at least worked).

Comment: BTW - I just noticed and fixed what I think is a bug in the comparison closure.   Namely, after it acquires both dates, if `date1 < date2` it returned `.compareLessThan`, otherwise `.compareGreaterThan`.  The only time it would return `.compareEqualTo` is when one or both of casts to `Date` fails.  That's clearly not right.  So it wouldn't compare equal dates as equal.   You probably should consider what the RightThing is for your app when the casts fail.  I updated my answer to fix the comparison, and to use trailing closure syntax.

Comment: Assuming `fatalError` is not an option for non-dates, one way is do the comparison such that `nil` is greater than non-nil values.  That will collect the invalid `Date` elements at the end, where it's easy and efficient to remove them after the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always have to spend time looking up what the deal is with `Unmanaged` because I need it so infrequently.  Apparently my guess at it in comments based on hazy memory of the last time I encountered `Unmanaged` worked for OP, so I'm putting it here.  Basically it comes down to both dereferencing the pointer using its `.pointee` property then calling `.takeRetainedValue()` on that, with appropriate optional unwrapping in between.

```
MDQuerySetSortComparatorBlock(query)
{
    guard let date1 = $0?.pointee?.takeRetainedValue() as? Date,
          let date2 = $1?.pointee?.takeRetainedValue() as? Date
    else
    {
        // Do you really want to treat non-dates as equal?
        return .compareEqualTo
    }
    
    if date1 < date2 { return .compareLessThan }
    return date1 == date2 ? .compareEqualTo : .compareGreaterThan
}
```

Exactly what to do with the possibility of the casts to `Date` resulting in `nil` depends on your app, but one possibility is do the comparison so that all the ones where the cast to `Date` fails, or where the pointer is genuinely `nil`, collect at the end.

```
MDQuerySetSortComparatorBlock(query)
{
    guard let date1 = $0?.pointee?.takeRetainedValue() as? Date else {
        return .compareGreaterThan
    }
    guard let date2 = $1?.pointee?.takeRetainedValue() as? Date else {
        return .compareLessThan
    }
    
    if date1 < date2 { return .compareLessThan }
    return date1 == date2 ? .compareEqualTo : .compareGreaterThan
}
```

Then when you get the query results, you can make a reverse pass to remove elements with invalid dates without needing to shift elements.